# Easiest way to vertically align elements in an HTML/Markdown paragrph

Tags: html, css, audio, markdown

### I'd like to vertically center the alarm name with the audio controls below:

[image: Tim-ta stock sound files.png]

---

## Current Code

The code is hybrid Markdown and HTML:

```html
## Stock Sound Files

These are Tim-ta stock sound files you can use when a timer task ends:
<br>
- **Alarm_03.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_03.mp3"></audio>
<br><br>
- **Alarm_05.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_05.mp3"></audio>
<br><br>
- **Alarm_12.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_12.mp3"></audio>
```

---

## Lots of Complicated Existing Solutions

There are lots of complicated ways of achieving the goal:

- [How do I vertically center text with CSS? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

I could add a `<div>` with a `class="centerAudioControl"` or something like that I guess. But, What is the easiest way considering there is already an ID?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind make the `line-height` of the text equal to the `height` of the `audio`. Vertical centering will be automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this??

```css
audio {vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
## Stock Sound Files

These are Tim-ta stock sound files you can use when a timer task ends:
<br><br>

- **Alarm_03.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_03.mp3"></audio>

<br><br>

- **Alarm_05.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_05.mp3"></audio>

<br><br>

- **Alarm_12.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;<audio controls="true" id="Alarm_12.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Works perfectly when you add `<style>` in front of the new line and `</style>` after the new line.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any solution without adding a div and using flexbox. It would also allow you to remove the `<br>` tags.

Here is what I would do:

```
## Stock Sound Files

These are Tim-ta stock sound files you can use when a timer task ends:
<div class="centerAudioControl">
   - **Alarm_03.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;
   <audio controls="true" id="Alarm_03.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="centerAudioControl">
  - **Alarm_05.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;
  <audio controls="true" id="Alarm_05.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="centerAudioControl">
  - **Alarm_12.mp3** &emsp;&emsp;
  <audio controls="true" id="Alarm_12.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

And then in your stylesheet:

```
.centerAudioControl {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Add margins as needed below */
}
```

Depening on your specific situation, you might also be able to remove the `&emsp;` and add `justify-content: space-around` to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent div wrapping all these and apply flex or grid like, if you give the wrapping div an id of centralAudioControl

HTML

```
<div id="centralAudioControl"> 
  ....Your contents...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#centralAudioControl {
    width:100%;
    display:grid;
    align-content:center;
}
```